# force index.php in url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've spent the last two hours reading stackoverflow and the apache manual trying to find a solution to this, but haven't found any, if a directory is access (http://domain.ext) I'd like to force index.php to appear in the url (http://domain.ext/index.php) if possible.

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?`

(but you will not see it in a browser because the rewrite engine just directs to the correct file/directory without changing the url from the browser)

with [R] tag you can redirect the user so the new url would appear in the browser

Answer (score 1):

I've just found what works for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ $1/folder/index.php$2 [R=301,L]
```